# Flask application - What is the difference between using logging and flask app.logger for a very basic flask application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In a flask application, we can use the root logger using logging.info("some message") to log information (and logging.debug/error/warning/critical). Also, we can set advanced settings using logging.basicConfig to configure the output location, format and level.

We also have option to do logger1 = logging.getLoger(**name**) And then log against that logger. I understand the general concept of logging handlers etc.

However, In flask there is app.logger also [example:  app.logger.info("some message")]. So what is the difference between using logging and flask app.logger for basic logging functionality for the flask application?